# Querying Data from DBMS in Hadoop Mapper Before Mapping

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm kind of new to MapReduce in Hadoop. I'm trying to process entries from many log files. The mapper process is quite similar with the one in [WordCount](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html) tutorial.

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
    }
}
```

The thing is instead of putting the word as the key for the reducer, I want to put a related data from a table in RDBMS. For example, the processed text are like this

```
apple orange duck apple giraffe horse lion, lion grape
```

And there is a table

```
name     type
apple    fruit
duck     animal
giraffe  animal
grape    fruit
orange   fruit
lion     animal
```

So, instead of counting the word, I want to count the type. The output would be like

```
fruit 4
animal 5
```

Let's say in the previous code, it will be like this

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String object = tokenizer.nextToken();
        //========================================
        String type = SomeClass.translate(object);
        //========================================
        word.set(type);
        output.collect(word, one);
    }
}
```

The `SomeClass.translate` will translate the object name to the type by querying from a RDBMS.

My questions

1. Is this doable? (and how to do that?)
2. What are the concerns? I came into understanding that the mapper will be run in more than one machines. So let's say there are `apple` words in more than one machines, how to reduce the number of database look-up for `apple`?
3. Or is there a very good alternative without doing translation in the mapper? Or maybe there is a common way to do this? (or is this whole question a really stupid question?)

**UPDATE**

I'm implementing it using Apache Hadoop on Amazon Elastic MapReduce and the translation table is stored in Amazon RDS/MySQL. I would really appreciate if you could provide some sample codes or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about minimizing DB queries, you could do this in two MR jobs: first do a standard word count, then use the output of that job to do the translation to type, and re-summing.

Alternatively, if your mapping table is small enough to fit in memory, you could start by serializing it, adding it to the DistributedCache, and then loading it into memory as part of the Mapper's setup method. Then there's no need to worry about doing the translation too many times, as it's just a cheap memory lookup.

Comment: the translation table is indeed quite small relative to the whole data to be summarized, but what are the limitations of DistributedCache?

Comment: DistributedCache simply copies files from one local FS to another. So there's probably not a limit on the size of those files other than the disk space, but very large files will affect performance.

Comment: For the first solution, how do you propose doing the translation job considering the environment (see the update in the question)? (bear with me, I'm really new with this)

Comment: As part of an EMR jobflow, you can specify a step that simply runs a shell script. From that script, you can run a mysql command such as `SELECT name, type FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` Then you can read that generated file as a normal csv file.

Comment: Now I got the idea. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the requirement, a join is done between the data in table and a file and count is done on the joined data. Based on the input size of the data there are different ways (M or MR only) join can be done. For more details on joining go through [Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/index.html) - Section 3.5.

Comment: Honestly, at first I was looking for a more practical tips using Hadoop MapReduce. But nevertheless, this is such a great reference for basic conceptual knowledge about MapReduce. Thank you very much!